# bootstrap carousel indicator not equal in distance?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently stack here and wondering why the bootstrap carousel indicator distance is not equal?

[image]

As you can see in the picture distance between 1st and 2nd indicator(bullets).

```
#carousel-example-generic-right .carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #990000;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
   width: 12px;
   height: 12px;
}
```

I only change the width and height of each bullet and the active state.

Working codepen [here](http://codepen.io/blitzz/pen/VarpWd)

It would be great if someone could help with this?

Comment: can you please add a [mcve]? the code you provided is not enough to figure out why you are seeing this behaviour

Comment: ok. thanks.. question has already been updated.

Comment: Your code looks to be working fine.  Are you sure you added the correct version of Jquery *before* adding the bootstrap files?

Comment: Yup, your pen does not have jquery added to it - as soon as you add jquery and re-run it, it works.  See my answer for a running sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks to be working fine.

However, you need to add the correct version of Jquery **before** adding the bootstrap files. See below:

**UPDATED**

included version stated in comments (not latest)

Based on comments, added screenshot:
[image]

```css
#carousel-example-generic-right {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  border: 1px solid #990000;
}
#carousel-example-generic-right .carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #990000;
}
#carousel-example-generic-right .carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
.item {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery 1.11.1  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div id="carousel-example-generic-right" class="carousel slide white box-shadow-rounded" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel" style="height:200px;">
  <ol id="aux-box-carousel-pagination" class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-example-generic-right"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-example-generic-right"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-example-generic-right"></li>
    <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#carousel-example-generic-right"></li>
  </ol>
  <div id="aux-box-carousel" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      Slide 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Slide 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Slide 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Slide 4
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am currently using jquery 1.11.1 and then bootstrap 3.3.5.

Comment: @blitzen12 I updated the answer to reflect the versions you are using... seems like the is no longer there when you add jquery before bootstrap

Comment: everything is working js/bootstrap functionality except for that indicator is not equal in distance.

Comment: @blitzen12 where is it not working? in the codepen? your site? where? I can see it works in the pen (you need to re-init the pen), I can see it working here when you run the snippet...  where is it not working? help me help you!!!

Comment: the carousel indicator does not have the same distance between the 1st and 2nd bullets. In your answer it seems to be working but in my codepen it seems like it's not?

Comment: Sorry @blitzen12 it works for me on the pen, browser and code snippet above (as I said) - what browser are you using? Give us details since I will not be able to help otherwise

Comment: I'm using google chrome version 49.0.2623.87..
So if it's working on your end so maybe mine is the problem.

Comment: I got same browser on Windows; what OS are you on?

Comment: Same here; weird... I'm on the road right now; I'll send a screenshot when I get home- shows all dots evenly spaced :(

Comment: For now I did some temporary solution to adjust the distance between 1st and 2nd bullets. Thanks for the help though.
I'll mark this as solved..

Comment: added screenshot -